# Which, if any, of the licences give you access to custom CSS styling?

Tags: css

I work for a charity that uses salesforce for an online database. Our admin profiles have full 'platform' or admin licences that appear identical to the what you get when signing up for a new developer account.

Our userbase has a different licence arrangement with a much simpler UI. I would like to explore the possibilities of injecting custom css (or in a perfect world even up to jquery, ajax etc), but it doesn't appear that we have access to these kinds of customization with our licence arrangements.

Which, if any, of the licences do allow you the ability to custom code your own CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no CSS or Javascript "injections" on the Salesforce Platform. There are some options for customizing user interface. I think you want to be able to modify UI in advanced way. For that Salesforce have a great framework called [Visualforce](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_intro_what_is_it.htm).

> The Visualforce framework includes a tag-based markup language,
>   similar to HTML, and a set of server-side “standard controllers” that
>   make basic database operations, such as queries and saves, very simple
>   to perform.

With Visualforce you can create and customize dynamic HTML-like web pages on the Salesforce platform. Of course CSS and AJAX are supported as well.

> Visualforce markup consists of Visualforce tags, **HTML, JavaScript**, or
>   any other Web-enabled code embedded within a single  tag.
>   The markup defines the user interface components that should be
>   included on the page, and the way they should appear.

To be able to use Visualforce you need to have one of the [following Salesforce edition](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_intro_editions.htm):

- Contact Manager
- Group
- Professional
- Enterprise
- Unlimited
- Performance
- Developer Edition

Additionally [following permissions](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_intro_permissions.htm) on the user profile are required for Visualforce development:

- Customize Application

Comment: After much fumbling around in the dark - I've come to discover just how powerful Visualforce is. It offers to provide many of the things I've been attempting to achieve with an external Rails application via the REST API.

That is, a markup view where I can embed the results of methods (via APEX) , UI control with CSS and Jquery and even slide in some AJAX. Returning to this question I appreciate how comprehensive it is, only wish I'd taken the advice to check visualforce out earlier!

Comment: @Huw Cool, you are wellcome :)

Answer (score 0):

What is your SFDC org edition - Group or Professional Edition?

I am hearing such things first time - I would recommend to create a support case with Salesforce.com and get the details.